# Use ReSharper TaskRunner in 32 and 64 bit

Tags: resharper, resharper-8.0

I am trying to use ReSharper TaskRunner to run unit tests on a 64-bit assembly.  However, for some reason ReSharper keeps starting JetBrains.ReSharper.TaskRunner.CLR4.exe which is a 32-bit app.

I made sure that my assembly specifies 64-bit architecture, I even tried setting default platform architecture to "Force tests to run in 64-bit process" via ReSharper Options dialog.

Nothing helps.  It still starts the 32-bit version of TaskRunner.

The only way I was able to make it work is by renaming files as suggested here: [nunit debugs in 64-bit, application is in 32-bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706710/nunit-debugs-in-64-bit-application-is-in-32-bit/3706862#3706862)

However, we need to run unit tests on both 32-bit and 64-bit assemblies so renaming files every time is not practical.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the test assembly project 64 bit? Both production code and test assembly need to be 64 bit - Resharper uses project settings to know which external runner to use.

Comment: Yes, both assemblies are 64-bit.

Comment: If you have both assemblies set to 64 bit, and you're also forcing it to be 64 bit, and it's still running the 32 bit version of the test runner, then there's a proper wacky bug going on. Can you report an issue - ideally with a repro solution? https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=RSRP&clearDraft=true&c=

Comment: It just started working for no apparent reason.  Must be some of those things are are fixed by reboot/reinstall.  Although in this case it took multiple reboots.

Answer (score 1):

It just started working for no apparent reason. Must be some of those things are are fixed by reboot/reinstall. Although in this case it took multiple reboots.